# Is there a way to re-map Insert to End on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard

Is there some way to use the registry hack in this post
[Windows INSERT key anti-functionality accidentally triggers; how to stop it permanently?](https://superuser.com/questions/31794/windows-insert-key-anti-functionality-accidentally-triggers-how-to-stop-it-perm/929907#929907)

to make the Insert key do the same as End? My Lenovo X240 keyboard has a compact keyboard with Fn keys mapped to things like changing brightness and volume by default, so I want to put FnLock on, but in that mode, the End key unwisely becomes Insert so I end up over-typing by mistake after trying to move to the End of the line.

But if I could change Insert to just still be interpreted as End, that would completely solve the problem.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

**KeyTweak 2.3** can help you with remapping in visual way and then create registry keys for you. It seems that its homepage is no longer available so you have to rely on [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=keytweak).

If you want to use key remappings also for your productivity, then open source tool [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) can be much better choice. You can [set up key remapping](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Remap.htm) like

> Insert::End

.

Bonus:

if your <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> bothers you, too, remap it as well. Example of 3 functions I use:

```
;send em dash on CapsLock
;note: Alt+CapsLock isn't mapped to anything so you can use it to toggle CapsLock as before
CapsLock::
    SendInput –
    If GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
        SetCapsLockState, Off
Return

;send bullet on Ctrl+Shift+CapsLock    
^+CapsLock::Send •

;run new Internet Explorer on Ctrl+Alt+CapsLock
^!CapsLock::Run "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -new
```