# How to run scripts with Windows is booted (like AutoHotKey or Java scripts)?

Tags: windows, boot, java, autohotkey

I need to run a certain script each time Windows goes up.

How could I execute it when starting Windows (that is, in boot)?

Comment: already has an answer: https://superuser.com/a/954957/456957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a shortcut to the script in your Start Menu, Startup folder.

https://scottiestech.info/2015/10/23/where-is-the-startup-folder-in-windows-10/

Press Winkey R (or otherwise open Run window).  Type **shell:startup**.  Click OK button.  Drag a shortcut to it.

Comment: I don't have a Winkey R on my keyboard but I know you meant to the famous Run program in Windows, I ran the syntax you mentioned and reached that folder. The moment I'll have that script ready to be executed I will use that. I thumbed up. Thx.