# cannot hibernate anymore (but standby)

Tags: windows-10, standby, energy-saving

for some reasons my Windows-10 desktop PC (HP) cannot hibernate anymore (but standby works fine).

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> shutdown /h
Element nicht gefunden.(1168)
```

(element not found 1168)

**Solution:**

Disabling secure boot in UEFI.
(thanks to "John Doe")

what I tried before:

- `powercfg /h OFF and then powercfg /h ON`
- disabling docker
- checking and disabling services, VPN drivers
- checking eventlog for suspicious entries
- ran power troubleshooting wizards,
- disabled fast startup
- making hiber file full size
- using a new and fresh user profile
- resetting power congig
- free up space on C drive (>30 GB),
- ran `powercfg -energy`  result: [Gist link](http://gist.github.com/rs38/cf9d56d15a2bf0b38a3d6d5dc6045862)
- unplugged USB Mass storage drive
- checked UEFI settings, updated BIOS
- updated IBM mass storage and chipset drivers as from HP homepage
- no wakeup events, no help in event viewer
- checked with procmon with different filters: will add results to the Gist
- filter `process = showdown.exe` : not helpful for me
- filter `path contains hiberfil`: not a single access!
- filter `path contains .sys`: not sure!
- checked pretty much every single hint in the two answers below
- further uninstalled pretty much a bunch of old software

etc.

I also checked with diskpart where I lately disabled a drive letter of a small recovery partition, but reverting this also did not help.

I am running out of ideas, and did not find **any hint to that error message with code 1168.**

Sorry for being late with proceeding with the debug ideas, but it consumes pretty much of time. The points will probably go to the answer with the most up votes, even if the big one is currently a big too much, may be it helps anyone else.

Also I need to underline, that hibernate is shown and supported and selectable and it was working a year ago

Comment: Hibernation requires a file to be written, called hyperfil.sys. I susect this file can't be made for some reason. By default this file would be located at C:\ and is hidden as a protected operating system file.

Comment: the file is present! (and will be created by `powercfg /h on`)

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't actually work?

Comment: yes of course! :) see error code

Comment: Yes, it didn't work before, but I meant, if you tried it since my replies and your testing.

Comment: yes, all steps in my initial question were of course tested. Sadly your comment was nothing new to try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80407/discussion-between-falco-alexander-and-lpchip).

Comment: How about trying sfc /scannow with administrative privileges? Maybe a system configuration file relating hibernation might be damaged.

Comment: I wonder if this command has helped even a single time for anyone?! I get angry anytime I read this from the MS support bots (human or not) in the MS community forums...

Comment: Run and post the results of [powercfg -energy](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rs38/cf9d56d15a2bf0b38a3d6d5dc6045862 @harrymc

Comment: (1) The Energy report warns about a bad driver for Shrew Soft VPN - try to delete this software to see if it causes the problem. (2) I don't know if hibernate is possible in [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows), but try it to see.

Comment: did all of this already. see my 3rd point "checking and disabling services, VPN drivers". normal clean boot -> no energy releated options afaik

Comment: The other option is to use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to disable/re-enable startup products in bunches, to find out if this is caused by some installed product.

Comment: I think that my above suggestion is a bit heavy and may not solve the problem. I have added an answer below which does not include it.

Comment: Add one more try to your list. On my case, I fixed the issue only removing dual boot with Grub. After reconfiguring boot with EasyBCD, hibernation works like a bear charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling secure boot resolved this error for me.

Comment: You are my hero!!! 
Since 2 years this is the one and only correct answer. 3 simple words!  I cannot beleive how many hours I spent doing dozends of different ideas...

Answer (score 8):

> *See lower sections for What is Waking Windows 10 and How to Prevent it and Error 1168*

## Why Can't Windows 10 Hibernate

*Hibernation is one of those issues that can have many causes, so please go through the list and try each option, and see if it works, even reboot and try again before moving on. Also you may need to revert settings or try a combination of them to succeed (for example combinations of Bios Settings, Fast Boot Off, Only Hibernation, Only Hybrid.)*

---

1. Check from the manufacturer that the system is (S4) hibernation-capable or hybrid capable (S3)

---

2. Check there is enough space on C: drive

---

3. Check Manufacturer Drivers are installed.

---

4. Elevated Command Prompt and running the command

   ```
   powercfg /h /type full
   ```

> Change the hibernation file type to full. This is not recommended on
>   systems with less than 32GB of storage.

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/power/system-power-states#hibernate-state-s4)

---

5. Elevated Command Prompt and Running the command to Resotre Defualts First Then Try Setting Hibernation File Type to Full

   ```
   Powercfg /restoredefaultschemes

   powercfg /h /type full
   ```

---

6. Elevated Command Prompt and running the command

> Report the sleep states available on the computer.
>     Will also attempt to report reasons why sleep states are unavailable.

```
    powercfg /availablesleepstates
```

or the short command:

```
    powercfg /a
```

> If Hibernate appears under "The following sleep states are available
>   on this system", then the feature is enabled. Keep in mind that
>   "hibernate" won't be available depending on your  hardware
>   configuration. Some reasons include:
>
> - Current video card driver doesn't support the power state, in which case you'll need to update your video adapter driver.
> - The power-saving options are supported by your computer, but they aren't enabled in the BIOS. (Note that instructions to access the BIOS
>     will vary depending on your PC manufacturer. Always check your
>     computer manufacturer's support website for details.)
> - In some cases, hibernation won't be available if "hybrid sleep" is enabled on your computer.
> - Your computer hardware is not compatible with the power-saving options.

[Source](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-hibernation-your-pc-running-windows-10)

---

7. Go into Power Plan Settings,

   - "Change advanced power settings"
   - Select "Sleep"
   - Try disabling "Hybrid Sleep" and set "Sleep" to "Never".

---

8. Be sure to try Hybrid only with settings like:

   - Go into Power Plan Settings,
   - Select "Sleep",
   - set "Sleep" to "Never".,
   - "Allow Hybrid Sleep" > "On",
   - "Hibernate After" "20 min".

---

9. Try disabling Fast Startup

Using the Fast Startup option is usually the root of many power related problems on Windows 10. You can use the following steps to disable this option to see if it fixes your problem.

> - Open Control Panel.
> - Click on Hardware and Sound.
> - Click on Power Options.
> - On the left pane, click the Choose what the power buttons do link.
> - Click the Change settings that are currently unavailable link.
> - Under “Shutdown settings,” clear the Turn on fast startup option.
> - Disable Fast Startup on Windows 10
> - Click the Save Changes button.

[Source](https://pureinfotech.com/fix-hibernate-problems-windows-10/)

Or via registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power
```

`HiberbootEnabled` DWORD, `0` = fast startup off, `1` = fast startup on

[Source](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/65090-can-t-enable-hibernation-regedit-powercfg-not-helping.html), [Source 2](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html)

---

10. Try to fix hibernation using Power Troubleshooter

> - Open Settings.
> - Click on Update & Security.
> - Click on Troubleshoot.
> - Under “Troubleshoot,” select the Power option.
> - Click the Run the troubleshooter button.
> - Continue with the on-screen directions to fix the hibernation problem.

[Source](https://pureinfotech.com/fix-hibernate-problems-windows-10/)

---

11. Dig into the Event Log:

    - Event Viewer (eventvwr), OK > Windows Logs > System
    - Event ID 42 in the System log from source Kernel-Power is the sleeping event.
    - Event ID 1 in the System log is for waking
    - See section thirteen below for detailed search.
    - Dated example of one user with [Event ID 41](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-41-source-Kernel-Power-eventno-9230-phase-1.htm) which resolved there issue
    - See if Microsoft, Manufacturer, or Third Part Sites have any information on the Event ID problems, also seek answers from like.
    - See section 2 below for more detailed overview.

[Source](https://www.forensicfocus.com/Forums/viewtopic/t=16470/)

---

**Resources:**

- [TenForums - How to fix Hibernate problems on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/fix-hibernate-problems-windows-10/)
- [TenForums - Enable or Disable Hibernate in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-enable-disable-hibernate-windows-10-a.html)
- [TenForums: How to Specify Hiberfile Type as Full and More](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25151-specify-hiberfile-type-full-reduced-windows-10-a.html)
- [Microsoft System Power States](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/power/system-power-states#hibernate-state-s4)
- [SU - I have a weird powercfg /a - no Hibernate  - Surface Pro 3](https://superuser.com/questions/1366601/i-have-a-weird-powercfg-a-response-and-no-hibernate-anywhere-surface-pro-3)
- [SU Why does my Windows 10 Laptop fail to hibernate sometimes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1342276/why-does-my-windows-10-laptop-fail-to-hibernate-sometimes)
- [Windows Central - Hibernation on your Windows 10 PC](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-hibernation-your-pc-running-windows-10)
- [TenForums - Can`t enable Hibernation! - Regedit POWERCFG help](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/65090-can-t-enable-hibernation-regedit-powercfg-not-helping-2.html)
- [Techjourney - Turn off Hybid Sleep](https://techjourney.net/turn-off-and-disable-hybrid-sleep-in-windows-10-8-1-8-7-vista/)
- [Tomshardware - How to query hibernation status](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/how-to-query-hibernation-status.2053389/)
- [Techrepublic - Investigate Windows sleep states with the PowerCfg command](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/investigate-windows-sleep-states-with-the-powercfg-command/)
- [pureinfotech How to fix Hibernate problems on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/fix-hibernate-problems-windows-10/)

---

### **What is Waking Windows 10 and How to Prevent it?**

---

1. Check last wake event in elvated cmd:

   ```
   powercfg –lastwake
   ```

If the Windows system is waken up by Windows Update, you will notice that the wake source is normally a service related to Windows Update:

Examples:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Wake Timer
    Owner: [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker)
    Owner Supplied Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.
```

> Or,

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Wake Timer
    Owner: [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (wuauserv)
```

---

2. Check your hardware that can wake the computer open elevated cmd:

   ```
   powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
   ```

   - Open device manger, right click properties of devices listed from above command, and disable ability to wake computer (inc Wake on Lan).
   - Or can do via cmd also (must include qotation marks) like below;

     powercfg -devicedisablewake "HID Keyboard Device"
     powercfg -deviceenablewake "HID Keyboard Device"

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/5lh4e6/pc_wakes_immediately_from_sleep/)

---

3. Disable Windows Update Power Management to Automatically Wake up the System via GDP

> - Open Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
> - Navigate to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates
> - Windows Components -> Windows Updates
> - Double click on Enabling Windows Update Power Management to automatically wake up the system to install scheduled updates policy
> - Set its setting to Disabled.
> - Click Apply / OK

[Source](https://techjourney.net/prevent-disable-windows-update-from-waking-up-pc-system/)

---

4. Disable Wake Timers

   - Control Panel --> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options.
   - Change plan settings of a power plan.
   - Change advanced power settings.
   - Expand Sleep -> Allow wake timers tree
   - Set all options under it (On battery and Plugged in) to Disable.

Check if wake timers are on in elevated cmd:

```
    powercfg -waketimers
```

[Source](https://techjourney.net/prevent-disable-windows-update-from-waking-up-pc-system/)

---

5. Prevent mcupdate_scheduled from Waking the Computer

> For system installed with Windows Media Center (WMC), a scheduled task
>   called mcupdate_scheduled is added, which is also able to wake the
>   computer up. Prevent this task from waking up the PC by:
>
> - Open the Task Scheduler.
> - Navigate to Microsoft -> Windows -> Media Center.
> - Right-click on the mcupdate_scheduled task and choose Properties.
> - On the Conditions tab, uncheck the Wake the computer to run this task option.
> - Click or tap on OK when done.

[Source](https://techjourney.net/prevent-disable-windows-update-from-waking-up-pc-system/)

---

6. Disable UpdateOrchestrator Reboot

   - Task Scheduler > Task Scheduler Library >
   - Microsoft > Windows > UpdateOrchestrator
   - Disable
   - [See source](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/09/20/disable-reboot-after-automatic-windows-updates/) here to disable for all users if showing up in point one of this section still.
   - [See here](https://techjourney.net/permanently-disable-prevent-automatic-restart-of-windows-update-in-windows-10/) if system is still waking the computer and reverting this task.

---

7. Disable Automatic Maintenance to Wake Up Computer in Local Group Policy Editor

   - Open "Local Group Policy Editor"
   - Navigate to Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Maintenance Scheduler
   - Open Automatic Maintenance WakeUp Policy policy to edit it.
   - Disable, Apply, OK

[Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/125608-enable-disable-automatic-maintenance-wake-up-computer-windows-10-a.html)

---

8. Check [Bios](https://superuser.com/a/494254/900431) and change power states

---

9. Download latest Bios and flash.

---

10. Try combination of fast startup, hybrid and hibernation.

---

11. Powershell Commands:

    - Run elevated Powershell and check 'Wake to Run':

> ```
>     Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun}
> ```

- Also check which task woke the system:

> ```
>     # Whether to print verbose information. 0 = normal; 1 = verbose
>     $verbose = 0
>     # Get the last wake timestamp in ISO format 24 hour clock, excluding seconds. E.g. '2016-12-16 00:49'
>     $format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
>     $powerLogs = Get-Eventlog -LogName System | Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending | ? { $_.EventID -eq 1 } | Select-Object -First 5
>     if ($verbose) {
>     Write-Host "Latest Power-Troubleshooter logs: " -ForegroundColor Cyan
>     $powerLogs | Format-List | Out-String | % { Write-Host $_.Trim() }
>     }
>     $wake_date = ($powerLogs | Select-Object -First 1).TimeGenerated.ToString($format)  
>     Write-Host "Last wake time: $wake_date" -ForegroundColor Cyan
>     Write-Host "Looking for tasks that ran on: $wake_date" -ForegroundColor Cyan
>     $lastWakeTasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | ? { $wake_date -eq $_.LastRunTime.toString($format) } 
>     $lastWakeTasks
> ```

[Source](https://theohbrothers.com/completely-disable-automatic-waking-from-sleep-or-hibernate-on-windows-10/)

---

12. Disable Automatic Restart

> Many a time the computer crashes, and the system restart itself. This
>   is by design. If you have left your PC on standby, and this happens,
>   the computer will restart, and if the problem repeats, this will keep
>   waking your PC.
>
> - Type System on the on the Search bar.
> - When it appears, click to launch.
> - On the left, select Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
> - Click on Settings under Startup and Recovery.
> - Uncheck mark on Automatically Restart and click on OK.

[Source](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/computer-turns-on-by-itself-windows)

---

13. Generate and review the sleep study report

    - Open elvated cmd
    - `powercfg /SLEEPSTUDY`
    - `start C:\Windows\system32\sleepstudy-report.html`

---

14. Generate and Review Power Energy Report, looking for errors that may conflict.

    - Run elvated CMD
    - Powercfg -energy
    - `start C:\Windows\system32\energy-report.html`

---

15. Dig into the Event Log

> - Open the Event Viewer
> - In the left-hand pane, drill down to Event Viewer (Local) > Windows Logs > System.
> - Right-click the “System” log and choose “Filter Current Log.”
> - In the Filter Current Log window, on the “Event sources” drop-down menu, select the “Power-Troubleshooter” option and then click “OK.”
>
> Back in the main Event Viewer window, you’ll see that we’ve filtered
>   out the hundreds of messages that aren’t relevant to our problem and
>   honed right in on the thing we care about: when the computer is waking
>   up from a low-power state. In the new filtered view, you can scroll
>   through every instance where your computer has woken over the duration
>   of the log (which should be hundreds of entries).
>
> What you should focus on is the time the event was logged (did it wake
>   at a time you were at the computer or was it a random
>   middle-of-the-night wake up call) and what Wake Source is indicated.
>
> If the Wake Source says “Power Button,” that indicates that the power
>   button on the PC was pressed to wake it up—an action you most likely
>   took yourself.
>
> If the Wake Source says something like “Device–HID-Compliant Mouse (or
>   Keyboard),” that indicates the PC is configured for key presses and
>   mouse movements to wake it.
>
> If the Wake Source lists your network adapter, that indicates your PC
>   is configured so that incoming network activity can wake it
>   up—something that’s useful if you like having your PC go to sleep but
>   still need it available to other network devices at times.
>
> If the Wake Source says “Timer,” it means that a scheduled task woke
>   the computer. The source information usually includes some indication
>   about the task that woke the PC. For example, in the previous
>   screenshot, I can tell that my PC was woken up in order to do a
>   scheduled restart after an update.
>
> You may also see something like “Wake Source: Unknown,” which is a bit
>   more cryptic but at least it tells when the PC was awoken.
>
> Once you’ve established that there is in fact a pattern of odd
>   computer wake up calls and you’ve identified the source, it’s time to
>   do something about it.

[Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/)

---

16. Check processor ID

    - Often the event log does not seem to show much, but if you take the Processor ID from Power-Troubleshooter Event you can locate the PID.
    - Open Task Manager (Alt + Ctlr + Deltet)
    - Click on Processes
    - Right Click on Title Bar and Select PID
    - Then Click on PID so the processor ID's list in order
    - Look for the Proccessor ID from the event, and see if that gives any clues.

[image: Check-PID-Windows-10]

[Source](https://www.vistax64.com/threads/vista-will-not-stay-asleep.172890/)

---

17. Diskpart, Partitions and Processor Monitor

    - As mentioned in the [following answer](https://superuser.com/a/1438339/900431), use [processor monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to review filter shutdown.exe but specifically as indicated in windows 7 example [here](https://superuser.com/questions/155308/why-doesnt-hibernate-work-any-more-windows-7). In this suggestion particularly if partition programs and diskpart has been used in the past, check for access and read, write issues and check mentioned post for solutions. Though nothing readily visible in your log.

---

18. Trying running Windows by turning off non Microsoft Services, and see if it works, to eliminate certain programs and services.

    - Windows Run `msconfig` --> services --> tick hide all 'Microsoft Services'. Review and turn of services, reboot check, be sure to sure back on afterwards. Services should properly be dealt with afterwards via `services.msc`.

---

19. Double check all hardware drivers and out of date software. Disable or uninstall items (particularly ones showing errors in reports or compatibility issues) to see if they are causing a problem.

---

20. Windows 10 May 1, 2019 — KB4501835 (OS Build 17763.439)

> Addresses an issue in Unified Write Filter (UWF) that prevents
>   Hibernate Once/Resume Many (HORM) from working as expected on Unified
>   Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) systems.

See Microsoft Article [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/4501835/windows-10-update-kb4501835).

---

21. Power Management Test Tool (PwrTest)

*While this may not solve your problem, it may be useful for easily trying different states for testing.*

> The power management test tool (PwrTest) is a test tool that enables
>   developers, testers, and system integrators to exercise and record
>   power management information from the system. You can use PwrTest to
>   automate sleep and resume transitions and record processor power
>   management and battery information from the system over a period of
>   time.
>
> PwrTest.exe is included in the Microsoft Windows Driver Kit (WDK). For
>   information about getting the WDK, see Windows Driver Kit Downloads.
>   To be able to use all PwrTest Scenarios...

- ([download instructions and source here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pwrtest))

  `pwrtest /?`

Go to Sleep – hybrid sleep – cycle 4 times – hibernate

```
pwrtest /sleep /h:y /c:4 /s:hibernate
```

Go to Sleep – hybrid sleep off – cycle 4 times – hibernate

```
pwrtest /sleep /h:n /c:4 /s:hibernate
```

---

22. Log Hibernation with Windows Performance Recorder and Review

    - Microsoft also offer help via there own debugging tool, follow the instructions and upload log file sharing service and share link on [Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/newthread?forum=Windows&threadtype=Questions&filter=update-windows_10&cancelurl=%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fwiki%2Fwindows_10-update%2Fsystem-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files%2Fbc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93%3Ftm%3D1439225104616), for hibernation event only, as described below.

`There is also an older version which is why it also mentions windows 7 ect.`

> **Windows performance recorder**
>
> Summary Windows performance recorder is a good tool to help us
>   diagnose computer problems.  It is relatively easy to install and run...
>
> In order to diagnose your problem you will need to download and
>   install the below.  We suggest you create a restore point before
>   running the trace.  It is safe in the vast majority of situations but
>   it cant hurt to have one....
>
> Install Windows Performance Toolkit by downloading ADK version ... 
>   [for Windows 10 here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=536682)
>
> **There is no need to install anything but the windows performance toolkit.**  > That is  about 100Mb.  You do not need to install the entire
>   ADK (or SDK)
>
> 1. Run ADKSetup.exe.
> 2. Click Install, specify the location where you want to install the Windows ADK features, and then click Next.
> 3. Select the Windows ADK features that you want to install (windows performance toolkit), and then click Install.
>
>    - [Help with installation (if needed) is here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2012/11/23/installing-the-windows-performance-toolkit-v5-0-wprui-wpr-xperf.aspx)
>
> When you have downloaded and installed it, open an elevated command
>   prompt and type the following
>
> WPRUI.exe (which is the windows performance recorder) You should see
>   this
>
> [image: Install-WPRUI]
>
> Unless your problem involves sleep, shutdown, waking, or reboot check
>   off the following boxes
>
> [image: Deselect-Problems]
>
> There are various options.  Choose the one that applies to your
>   situation
>
> [image: Select-Issue]
>
> If you want to reduce the size of the file you can choose "Light"
>   instead of verbose
>
> [image: Reduce-Size-Or-Verbose]
>
> Please run the trace when you are experiencing the problem
>
> When you are ready or are experiencing the problem Click Start
>
> Let it run for 30 secs  and save the file (it will show you where it
>   is being saved and what the file is called)
>
> It will generate a large file and the longer you run it the larger it
>   will be ZIPPING the file reduce the size by a factor of 10 so a 10 Gig
>   Etl=1 Gig zipped file  Please dont upload an ETL file that is larger
>   that 4 Gb unzipped.  If your is bigger run a shorter trace
>
> Zip the file and upload to us on Onedrive (or any file sharing
>   service) and give us a link to it in your next post. It will be faster
>   for you to upload and for us to download.  Be sure to upload the file
>   that ends in "ETL" not the smaller folders that end in PDB!!!
>
> If your problem involves sleep, hibernation, shutdown, or reboot you
>   will need to configure WPR differently.  For example for a reboot
>   issue configure it like this (this will reboot your computer as soon
>   as you click start so close your work)
>
> For shutdown issues configure it like this
>
> [image: Shutdown-Issues-Example]
>
> ONCE YOU HAVE RUN THE TRACE UPLOAD IT TO ONEDRIVE OR ANY OTHER FILE
>   SHARING SERVICE AND PUT A LINK TO IT IN YOUR NEXT POST.
>
> There are some special situations where you need to configure WPR
>   differently.  These are only necessary if they apply to you
>
> To correctly capture event stacks on 64-bit systems that are running
>   Windows® 7, disablepagingexecutive should be set to On, and the system
>   must be rebooted before you start performance recording. For 32-bit
>   systems that are running Windows 7 and for all systems that are
>   running Windows 8, you can operate performance recording without
>   setting disablepagingexecutive to On.  To do this type wpr
>   -disablepagingexecutive  in an elevated command prompt
>
> ‘If you have a question about this topic, [Ask the community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/newthread?forum=Windows&threadtype=Questions&filter=update-windows_10&cancelurl=%2Fen-us%2Fwindows%2Fwiki%2Fwindows_10-update%2Fsystem-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files%2Fbc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93%3Ftm%3D1439225104616)’.

[Microsoft Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-performance-recorder/a1648e8c-50c7-4243-9f1d-4216385c7ff3)

---

23. As mentioned in the following [answer](http://[following%20answer][27]) the language pack is repeatedly showing up in the process monitor log.

    - Try uninstalling Language Pack App
    - (Can you change to another language or remove it without harm?)
    - **Make sure you have a copy of the language pack and a system backup first!**

      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackde-DE_17763.13.35.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
    - If this is an app, then can use superuser powershell grid view command [here](https://superuser.com/a/1061020/900431) for single user or all users.

---

24. Check all scheduled tasks

    - Open elvated cmd
    - `schtasks /query /FO TABLE /v > 0 & notepad 0`
    - Turn off wordwrap in notepad and review
    - If any offending items open task scheduler and disable.

[source](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/658164/pc-woke-up-for-no-reason/)

---

25. Check startup folders, registry keys and services for viruses/malware and potential programs and scripts which could be an issue:

    - Folders

> ```
>     C:\Users\$USER-NAME-HERE$\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
>     C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
> ```

- Registry Keys

> ```
>     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
>     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 
>     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
> ```

- Or further digging can be done with [AutoRuns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) for windows.

[Source](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-add-or-remove-startup-apps-in-windows-10/), [Source 2](https://superuser.com/a/1233702/900431)

---

26. Try System Restore or System Rebuild (if bios and drivers have already been restored, and system scan done). If rebuilding, be sure to test at each stage, to see what the issue is.

    - Or try a fresh install on separate drive and boot into see if hibernation is working. Also can use a free tool like [flash boot](https://www.prime-expert.com/flashboot/features_v3/install-full-featured-windows-to-usb-thumbdrive/) or [rufus](https://www.intowindows.com/rufus-to-create-windows-to-go-usb-drive/).

---

27. Contact Manufacturer troubleshooting tools and support. For this computer, HP windows 10 Hibernation issue support is [here](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c03383935). Can also contact Manufacturer for assistance.

---

**Further Reading**

- Source Links Above
- [How do I prevent the Windows 10 Maintenance Activator from waking my PC randomly (even after disabling wake timers)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1131231/how-do-i-prevent-the-windows-10-maintenance-activator-from-waking-my-pc-random)
- [How to Disable “Allow This Device to Wake the Computer](https://appuals.com/how-to-disable-allow-this-device-to-wake-the-computer/)

---

### **Error 1168**

> ```
> ERROR_NOT_FOUND
>
> 1168 (0x490)
>
> Element not found.
> ```

Source: [Microsoft Docs - System Error Codes (1000-1299)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-)

- *Also a Windows 7 [wiki](http://www.wiki-errors.com/err.php?wiki=1168) states the following:*

> The 1168 error may be caused by windows system files damage. The
>   corrupted windows system files entries can be a real threat to the
>   well being of your computer.
>
> There can be many events which may have resulted in the system files
>   errors. An incomplete installation, an incomplete uninstall, improper
>   deletion of applications or hardware. It can also be caused if your
>   computer is recovered from a virus or adware/spyware attack or by an
>   improper shutdown of the computer. All the above actives may result in
>   the deletion or corruption of the entries in the windows registry.
>   This corrupted registry will lead to the missing and wrongly linked
>   information and files needed for the proper working of the
>   application.

[Source](http://www.wiki-errors.com/err.php?wiki=1168)

Suggestion of this answer; run scans suggested above, make sure of system integrity. Check event log and sleep report to find information. Then go through each step and see if it helps. Bios is a common problem, devices waking the computer ect.

*Error Code mentioned also at*

- [PC Hibernating Overnight with Advanced Power Options set to Never, then upon wake it's rebooting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/pc-hibernating-overnight-with-advanced-power/5606fd62-915f-4c60-86e7-20bbe37aaa18)
- [Repadmin - showism failed with status 1168 0x490 Element not found.](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29136101/repadmin-showism-failed-with-status-1168-0x490-Element-not-found.html)
- [The error 0X80070490(Element not found) when you are installing](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2011/06/19/the-error-0x80070490element-not-found-when-you-are-installing-a-service-pack-or-update/)
- [OSUninstallWindow DISM Difficulties](https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/blog/Windows-Enterprise-Desktop/OSUninstallWindow-DISM-Difficulties)
- [How do you fix Webroot SecureAnywhere error 10 and 1168?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-fix-Webroot-SecureAnywhere-error-10-and-1168)
- [Uninstall 1803 update after 10 day grace period Error 1168](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2149108-uninstall-1803-update-after-10-day-grace-period-error-1168)

---

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I aready tried every single point if this list, and it still instantly exits hibernate. to make clear: hibernate is available and can be used, it starts to standby, shutting off monitors, exiting RDP, but it instantly is back and awake.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander, if none of this solved your problem, your computer may need an exorcist.  :-)

Comment: sorry for delay, I'll do my best during the week end, as this only happens on my private HP elitedesk computer!

Comment: see my updates.

Comment: sadly nothing changed and I run out of time to try every combination of potential fixes. thanks a lot for your help and patience, it will surely help someone else!

Comment: These things are very time consuming! I totally understand. @FalcoAlexander If you do find a bit of spare time, I would try point 22 and lodge it with Microsoft, that way they may be able to replicate it and add a fix in an update. And save you having to rebuild. Peace.

Comment: today the semi annual 1903 update was installed (blazingly fast) and nothing changed. I can remember in the past there was a similar situation where it changed from hibernation work ok to not-ok or vice versa. Will try point 22 as a got some time left

Comment: meanwhile it appears the computer is not able to do fast startup anymore, which is in fact is nothing else than hibernate. I also removed some more suspect apps and drivers and startup from it. For me this means, it does not have a problem with energy states but simply being not able to write on the partition or hiber file. still missing some errors in logs despite this error 1168

Comment: @FalcoAlexander hmmm I suggest doing the dreaded and re installing a fresh copy. See if everything works with Microsoft choosing the drivers. If still not, then move onto installing drivers from manufacture. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer contains many troubleshooting methods for sleep/hibernate
problems. I list below one other method, even though I'm not convinced
that any of them will help with the problem:

- Create a new power plan using
  *Control Panel > Power Options > Create a power plan*.

However, the problem is that Windows announces that a file was
not found, meaning that a Windows file has gone missing.

I propose the following:

1. Try to find which file is missing and bring it over from another Windows
   computer
2. Repair Windows, if the missing file cannot be located.

The best tool for investigating such a problem is
[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon),
for tracing which requested file or module is missing.

There are many resources available for using it, for example:

- [How to Use Process Monitor to Track Registry and File System Changes](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/process-monitor-track-events-generate-log-file/)
- [TribeLan Process Monitor](https://community.tribelab.com/course/view.php?id=8)

If this fails, a solution that will return all Windows components to a known
state is to do a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Using this method is possible since Windows is bootable.
You will need a the latest Windows installation ISO, as described
in the article.

This will conserve all your installed applications and almost all Windows settings.
But as it is still a serious operation, ensure that your backups are good.

Comment: I have two procmon native logs from during hibernate fail, would like to share but they are quite big and also a bit private. any idea?

Comment: Use a filter for open-file or for load-module.

Comment: I got your files, with much data. It might be that the problem is that the Dutch language folder is partially missing. Folder is `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePackde-DE_17763.13.35.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe`. If that's not it, then I think that the In-place Upgrade is your best bet. As said above, ensure good backups, perhaps also a total disk backup.

Comment: will have a look at the german language stuff...the next in-place upgrade is coming soon, isn't it? Redstone 6 aka Win 10 1903

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant German, not Dutch. Applying the new major Windows update might also fix this error.

Comment: why do you think it will have a problem with that LanguageExperiencePack?

Comment: There is a chance that the Windows update will reinstall the missing file. I don't think the missing file will cause any problem for this update.