# Disable INSERT key in all applications

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, windows-registry

The `Insert` and `Caps Lock` keys just get in the way. This [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/31794/windows-insert-key-anti-functionality-accidentally-triggers-how-to-stop-it-perm) asks how to disable `Insert`, but appears to be for Windows 7 because it does nothing for me on Windows 8.1. I've been able to disable `Caps Lock` using this registry entry:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00`

but the suggested solution:

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Value Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,52,e0,00,00,00,00`

continues to overwrite text in various text editors, even after a reboot. To be clear, I would like to disable BOTH `Caps Lock` and `Insert`, ideally in a single registry key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify **three entries** in the map as described in [Scan code mapper for keyboards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128267(v=vs.85).aspx).

For instance, I use next remapping on my Windows 8.1 (but since *XP* times): <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> behaves the same way as <kbd>LShift</kbd> and its functionality is remapped to <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd>; of course, the latter functionality is lost i.e. <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd> now behaves the same way as <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> would before all remapping. That remapping appears in the registry as follows:

```
==> reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
    Scancode Map    REG_BINARY    0000000000000000030000002A003A003A00460000000000
```

i.e. in terms of registry editor export:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,2a,00,3a,00,3a,00,46,00,\
  00,00,00,00
```

Description: (the following table contains these entries broken into `DWORD` columns ([little-endian format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) preserved) and the words are *described* in hexadecimal i.e. swapped)

```
00,00,00,00 ,00,00,00,00 ,03,00,00,00 ,2a,00,3a,00 ,3a,00,46,00 ,00,00,00,00
00000000     00000000     03000000     2A003A00     3A004600     00000000
│            │            │            │            │            │
│            │            │            │            │            └─ Null terminator
│            │            │            │            │
│            │            │            │            ├─ ScrollLock -> CapsLock
│            │            │            │            ╘═     0x0046 -> 0x003A
│            │            │            │
│            │            │            ├─ CapsLock -> LShift
│            │            │            ╘═   0x003A -> 0x002A
│            │            │
│            │            └─ Three entries in the map (including null entry)
│            │
│            └─ Header: Flags. Set to all zeroes.
│
└─ Header: Version. Set to all zeroes.
```

Read [Keyboard-internal scancodes](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/specs/kbd/scancodes-9.html) and  [Microsoft Keyboard Scan Code Specification](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJ5bfPtMzMAhXLvBoKHQa4Bi0QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F1%2F6%2F1%2F161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c%2Fscancode.doc&usg=AFQjCNFpwWwiM0iIlms4bSL-fVCvRK4K2w&sig2=s70GN2GI08nYWvGN3OOmbA) for <kbd>Insert</kbd> key scan code value. I would say `0xE052`  however can't see the sense of next note (applied to <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>, arrows etc.):

> These keys may have additional “shift” and/or “unshift” scan codes
>   preceding the Base Make code and following the Base Break code,
>   depending upon the current state of Num Lock and the state of Shift
>   key/s (when multiple keys are held down at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to disable <kbd>Insert</kbd> in the text editor itself. For example:

- Notepad++, Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Scintilla commands, change `SCI_EDITTOGGLEOVERTYPE` to `None` and click `Apply`
- Visual Studio, Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, remove the shortcut binding for `Edit.OvertypeMode`
- Eclipse, Windows > Preferences > General > Keys, find the `Toggle Overwrite` command in the `Text Editing` category and click `Unbind command`

Feel free to extend the list above if you know of ***major*** text editors that offer the ability to remove <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Comment: The "while not directed at your specific question" should have been a clue that this post is not appropriate for this location. This is good information, just not here.