# Disable caps lock, num lock, and insert(numpad-0)

Tags: windows, keyboard, regedit, capslock, numlock

Following up on the questions [Permanently disable num lock in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/688889/permanently-disable-num-lock-in-windows) and [Windows INSERT key anti-functionality accidentally triggers; how to stop it permanently?](https://superuser.com/questions/31794/windows-insert-key-anti-functionality-accidentally-triggers-how-to-stop-it-perm), I am trying to disable caps lock, num lock, and insert (or numpad-0 on my keyboard). Combining those answers, I tried the following. Apparently I've got it wrong. It does disable caps lock and num lock, but numpad-0 still puts me into overtype mode, which I never want, ever ever, ever, ever.

1. Click Start > Run
2. Type "regedit"
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`
4. While Keyboard Layout has focus, go to Edit > New > Binary Value
5. Enter "Scancode Map" as the name
6. Enter the following as the Data:

   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     06 00 00 00 3A 00 00 00
     00 00 3A 00 00 00 45 00
     00 00 52 E0 00 00 00 00
     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

How can I permanently disable all three of the evil modal keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did it for me. Finally. Save the following as a file, with a name like "DisableCapslockNumlockInsert.reg" (The ".reg" extension is important; the rest doesn't matter.) Double click it and click through all the warnings. Then restart your computer.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,05,00,00,00,00,00,3a,00,00,00,52,e0,\
  0b,00,52,00,00,00,45,00,00,00,00,00
```

A bit of explanation:

- I'm pretty sure the backslash is a telling it that the data go to the next line. If your data are all on a single line, you probably don't need it.
- the "05" is one plus the number of keys you are mapping.
- the "00,00,3a,00" disables caps lock.
- the "00,00,52,e0" disables insert.
- the "0b,00,52,00" remaps the insert on your number pad to the "0" key. If you prefer to just disable this key, use "00,00,52,00" instead.
- the "00,00,45,00" disables num lock.
- The zeroes other than the above are simply part of the format for that particular registry key.

Alternatively, to remap caps lock to control:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,05,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,52,e0,00,00,45,00,\
  0B,00,52,00,00,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 0):

The Regedit way is confusing, I've tried it myself, get AutoHotkey and right click, new, autohotkey script and paste this in:

`CapsLock::return
NumLock::return
Ins::return`