# When I press the space bar it deletes the letters after it

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

How do I change the settings to where I can press the space bar and it put a space after the letter instead of deleting the letters after it. For example, when I have a sentence like " I hav to go." And I want to put the cursor after the v to add an e it will end up like this "I haveto go" then I go to put a space between them and it does this " I haveo go" then add another space " I have go" then "I havego" then another space and it does the same thing " I haveo" and it deletes the letters after it.

Comment: @Burgi: A broken keyboard will rarely malfunction in such a regular fashion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows INSERT key anti-functionality accidentally triggers; how to stop it permanently?](https://superuser.com/q/31794/173513)

Comment: I think that 'Insert' is only partialy responsible. I have the same feature: on one half of my space key it's written: 'Space * Backspace'. If I hold both space keys for 3-5 seconds then it switches betweeen Sapce/Backspace. If I hit space now, it will remove character instead of adding space. 
Can't post as answer, question closed without valid respnose IMO
https://techland.time.com/2012/09/20/new-microsoft-keyboard-splits-space-bar-left-side-used-as-backspace-key/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is caused by the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key on your keyboard, it replaces the letters to the right as you explained.

Simply press the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key and it will deactivate the replace mode. Pressing it the second time reactivates it.

Answer (score 111):

I guess you are in replace mode, just press the ["Insert" key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) on your keyboard.

---

From comments (Thanks @FabioTurati)

> The cursor is different: in Insert mode it's a vertical bar placed between two letters, whereas in Overtype mode it's an underscore, and it is under one letter (the one which will be overwritten if you type something)

Comment: Also known as ***Overtype** mode* as opposed to *Insert mode*. Look for OVR or INS at the right end of the status bar to determine which mode the editor is in.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key

Comment: Absolutely. And it isn't limited to Notepad++ either, many text editors (and plenty of other programs) support this mode.

Comment: are there even legitimate use cases for this annoying mode?

Comment: @undefined: I use it regularly when I want to overtype *d'uh*. It's also very useful when working with tables in plain text files (e.g. in tabular plain text databases or when adding a table to a markdown document).

Comment: @undefined: To extend phresnel's comment, if you've ever made ASCII art, you'd use OVR religiously as well.

Comment: ...and now that I think about it, I should be using overtype more often when writing in my [programming esolang](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console). Its a 2D language, so needing to overtyping NOP commands is a regular occurrence. I feel silly for not realizing this sooner, as overtype mode is more often an annoyance rather than a desired behavior.

Comment: The insert mode, would be replacing those letters with spaces, not deleting them though...

Comment: @undefined a response along a different path: I have been using [Ctrl] and/or [Shift] together with [Insert] and [Delete] since before Windows came along, and after I switched away from QWERTY which made [Ctrl]+[X]/[C]/[V] inconvenient.